# psycopg2 importError Python3.12 on Windows

Tags: python, postgresql, powershell, windows-10, psycopg2

I have a python script that I built over the last 2 weeks using python3.10.
The script did run fine 100s of times until I reinstalled python/modules.

I recently upgraded to Python 3.12. I had to pip install all of the modules again but now for some reason when I try to run my script the psycopg2 module keeps failing with the follow error:

```
packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am running my script from Visual Studio Code 1.83 in a powershell prompt.

I have tried uninstalling, clearing pip cache and reinstalling.

I have tried suggested psycopg2-binary package.

I tried updating Microsoft Visual C++ update. I tried reinstalling python 312.

I assume this is some weird windows dependency issue.
Can anyone please help me troubleshoot? I am happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: What version of `psycopg2` are you using? Python 3.12 support was only added in 2.9.9 which was released October 3, 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Should be releasing a fix for version 3.12 on Windows soon.
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1628

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, unfortunately could not find any solution other than downgrading python version from 3.12 to 3.11.6, now it is working well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain a standalone package, not requiring a compiler or external libraries, by installing the `psycopg2-binary` package from PyPI:

```
$ pip install psycopg2-binary
```

worked on python version 3.12.2